# How can I specify the column heading within a WPF datagrid for an observable collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following code that I'm populating a WPF datagrid with:

```
var customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

foreach (
    var customer in
        collListItem.Select(
            item =>
            new Customer
                {
                    Persona = item["Persona"].ToString(),
                    CustomerName = item["Title"].ToString()
                }))
{
    customers.Add(customer);
}

this.dataGridOutstandingOrders.ItemsSource = customers;
```

Based upon my **customer** class:

```
public class Customer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the persona.
    /// </summary>
    public string Persona { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the customer name.
    /// </summary>
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is once I bind my data to the WPF datagrid the columns come through as the names of my variables in `Customer();`. Instead I'd like to be able to specify the name of the column (so for example `CustomerName` would be `Customer Name`). Is there a way to do this with annotations in my customer class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `[Display(Name="Customer Name")]` attribute on CustomerName property:

```
public class Customer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the persona.
    /// </summary>
    public string Persona { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the customer name.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name="Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Edited :
You need to handle AutoGeneratingColumns Event for the datagrid:

```
private void DG_OnAutoGeneratingColumns(object sender,DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propdesc = e.PropertyDescriptor as System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor;
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute displayAttrib =
            pd.Attributes[typeOf(ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)] as System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute;
if(displayAttrib!=null)
{
   e.Column.Header = displayAttrib.Name;
}
```

Comment: I'll check this again but I believe this wasn't working for me (see comment on Hari's answer)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you defined your `DataGrid` in Xaml, but below code should work.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Person" Binding="{Binding Persona }" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Name" Binding="{Binding CustomerName  }" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really answer the question. I'm looking for a way to approach this outside of XAML. Ideally I'd like to use data annotations as datagrids appear to ignore the DisplayName annotation.